# Todas as tags de realce de linguagem

Tags: suporte

Quais são todas as tags de realce de linguagem disponíveis aqui no SOpt?

Não sei se existe essa parte no Help, mas pelo menos não achei.

Comment: Você se refere às tags em si ou aos comentários do tipo `<!-- language: lang-xx -->` (que permitem fazer realce de sintaxe)? Se for as tags mesmo, não há uma lista delas - mesmo porque tags novas podem ser criadas pelos usuários [com certo nível de privilégios] a qualquer momento. Se for sobre o realce de sintaxe, [aqui tem uma lista](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/150/215).

Comment: Era esta lista que eu queria, de realce de sintaxe. Obrigado!

Comment: Não acho que seja duplicada. Uma pergunta se refere se é possível, e a outra pede a lista. Ainda que aquela responda esta perfeitamente, o foco da pergunta é diferente.